# How to find input parameter for Sequential in keras for tensorflow object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I was successful in running the inference for [TensorFlow Hub Object Detection Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_object_detection.ipynb#scrollTo=rOvvWAVTkMR7) on `google colab`

the model I have loaded

```
model_display_name = 'CenterNet HourGlass104 Keypoints 512x512'
model_handle = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/centernet/hourglass_512x512/1'
```

Trying to use [Transfer learning with TensorFlow Hub](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub.ipynb#scrollTo=PWUmcKKjtwXL)

```
IMAGE_SHAPE = (None, None)

classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(model_handle, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,))
])
```

I get this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-081693dbe40a> in <module>()
      4 
      5 object_detector = tf.keras.Sequential([
----> 6     hub.KerasLayer(object_detector_model, input_shape=Object_Detector_IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,))
      7 ])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    690       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    691         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 692           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    693         else:
    694           raise

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "keras_layer" (type KerasLayer).

in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py", line 229, in call  *
        result = f()

    ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
      inputs: (
        Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 1, None, None, 3), dtype=float32))
      input_signature: (
        TensorSpec(shape=(1, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None)).


Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1, None, None, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=None
```

How do I alter `IMAGE_SHAPE` for this, I am confused?

Need help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues, this model expects the input type `tf.uint8` when specifying the `input_shape` and according to the [source](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/centernet/hourglass_512x512/1) it returns an output dictionary. Since the `Sequential` API does not work with multiple outputs, you will have to use the `Functional` API.

Simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model_display_name = 'CenterNet HourGlass104 Keypoints 512x512'
model_handle = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/centernet/hourglass_512x512/1'

k_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_handle, input_shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8)
```

And with the `Functional` API:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model_display_name = 'CenterNet HourGlass104 Keypoints 512x512'
model_handle = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/centernet/hourglass_512x512/1'

k_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_handle, input_shape=(None, None, 3))

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8)
outputs = k_layer(inputs)
classifier = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
print(classifier.summary())
```

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
                                                                 
 keras_layer_9 (KerasLayer)  {'num_detections': (1,),  0         
                              'detection_boxes': (1,             
                             100, 4),                            
                              'detection_classes': (1            
                             , 100),                             
                              'detection_scores': (1,            
                              100)}                              
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: [models/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt) being loaded they are about 90 labels.

Comment: I am trying to replicate a classification [Transfer learning with TensorFlow Hub](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub.ipynb#scrollTo=PWUmcKKjtwXL) to object detection When already training for [TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-tutorial) already exists

Comment: Thank you for help. I think, I will face few a lot of hurdles which I don't have time for if I follow `keras` path for training as no tutorial exists with `tensorflow 2 object detection`